# opening and closing the expanded-panel-list by tapping the headers of each list instead of the right arrow in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to toggle the each list in the expanded panel list by tapping on each header on this list.
bellow is my code, and i don't know if its possible to achieve that by adding ontap or onpressed function. thank you.

```
Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: w * 0.05, right: w * 0.05),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ExpansionPanelList(
                          children: [
                            ExpansionPanel(
                              isExpanded: _isOpen[0],
                              headerBuilder: (context, isOpen) {
                                return Row(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                                    Container(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              "Ball Games ⚽ ",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 20,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  color: Color(0xff262626)),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(height: 5),
                                            Text(
                                              "Select Sport from the ball games\nsection",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  color: Color(0xff696F79)),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              },
                              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    _ballGames(),
                                    // _ballGames(),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            ExpansionPanel(
                              isExpanded: _isOpen[1],
                              headerBuilder: (context, isOpen) {
                                return Row(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                                    Container(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              "Racket & Bat ",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 20,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  color: Color(0xff262626)),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(height: 5),
                                            Text(
                                              "Select sport from the racket & bat\nsection",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  color: Color(0xff696F79)),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              },
                              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    _racketAndBat(),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            ExpansionPanel(
                              isExpanded: _isOpen[2],
                              headerBuilder: (context, isOpen) {
                                return Row(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                                    Container(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              'Winter ',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 20,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  color: Color(0xff262626)),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(height: 5),
                                            Text(
                                              "Select sport from the winter\nsection",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  color: Color(0xff696F79)),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              },
                              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    _winter(),
                                    // _myListView(),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            ExpansionPanel(
                              isExpanded: _isOpen[3],
                              headerBuilder: (context, isOpen) {
                                return Row(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                                    Container(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              'Water ‍♀️ ',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 20,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  color: Color(0xff262626)),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(height: 5),
                                            Text(
                                              "Select sport from the water\nsection",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  color: Color(0xff696F79)),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              },
                              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    _water(),
                                    // _myListView(),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            ExpansionPanel(
                              isExpanded: _isOpen[4],
                              headerBuilder: (context, isOpen) {
                                return Row(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                                    Container(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              'Others ',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 20,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  color: Color(0xff262626)),
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(height: 5),
                                            Text(
                                              "Select sports from the others\nsection",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  color: Color(0xff696F79)),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              },
                              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    _others(),
                                    // _myListView(),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                          expansionCallback: (i, isOpen) {
                            setState(() {
                              _isOpen[i] = !isOpen;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

i can easily toggle the list by tapping on the right arrow at the right but i want to use the whole header of each instaed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your desired result you have a `property` in **ExpansionPanel** named `canTapOnHeader`. You just have to set it `true` that's it.

```
canTapOnHeader : true,
```